# x86 Assembly error in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit

I have the following assembly code that i got from a x86 assembly tutorial online:

```
section .text
   global _start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)

start:              ;tells linker entry point
   mov  edx,len     ;message length
   mov  ecx,msg     ;message to write
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

   mov  eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;string to be printed
len equ $ - msg     ;length of the string
```

I saved the above code in a file "hello.asm"

now when i compile and link it in my terminal, i get the following error!

```
root@mac:~# nasm -f macho hello.asm && gcc -o hello hello.o

ld: warning: ignoring file hello.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): hello.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You have 64 bit system apparently. Use `gcc -m32`. Also note your code is for linux not mac so it will probably not work.

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? I'm not familiar with programming in OSX, but I believe vector 80h is in specific reference to a vector in the Linux IVT; this will not work on OSX.

Comment: I am following this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_basic_syntax.htm

a friend suggested this, and i am totally confused because i dont know assembly and he doesnt know how mac works!

Answer (score 1):

The code you have **is** valid Linux code. However, it is **not** valid MacOS code. This is because the system interrupt `int 0x80` is meant to call the Linux system kernel not the MacOS one. If you have a older version of MacOS that is Linux based this might still work.

The other problem is that this code is 32-bit and you are compiling it like 64-bit code. To solve this you should add `-m32` to the `gcc` command.

Comment: Modern MacOS doesn't support 32-bit executables.  Older MacOS versions do, and `int 0x80` is the system-call instruction for 32-bit code.  But the calling convention is different, like FreeBSD they want system call args on the user-space stack, starting at 4 bytes above ESP.  (So they're already in the right place in a libc wrapper function like `write()`.)  The call numbers are probably also different, I forget if 32-bit MacOS wants some high bits set the way they do for 64-bit syscall numbers.

Comment: I'm not aware of any older MacOS versions ever being Linux based.  MacOS X was derived from FreeBSD, and the kernel + libc aren't GPL-licensed so can't include any code from Linux.  The first 2 sentences are correct, this is 32-bit Linux code and can't work on a Mac.  (People should look for a tutorial that matches their OS and CPU, not try to port tutorials at the same time they're learning the basics from them.)  The rest of this answer is pretty much wrong.  Yes there's a mismatch in trying to link into a 64-bit executable, but `-m32` probably won't work even with correct MacOS code.